# Focus outline is invisible in Chrome when using a keydown handler to control focus

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, focus, outline

I have an `<input type="text" />`.

When I <kbd>Shift+Tab</kbd> from the textfield, I want to focus on an `li > a`. I can't rely on the native tabbing behavior in this case, because I have an anchor element in between the `<input />` and the target `<a />` that I don't want to give focus to.

Thus, I add a keydown listener that forces focus to the `<a />` that I care about.

In Chrome however, when I focus on the `<input />` and <kbd>Shift+Tab</kbd> from the `<input />`, focus goes to the last `<a />`, but the outline is invisible. If I do another <kbd>Shift+Tab</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> to land back onto B, I now see the outline.

```js
document.getElementById("f").addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
  if (e.key === "Tab" && e.shiftKey) {
      e.preventDefault();
      document.querySelector("#list1 > li:last-child > a").focus();
  }
});
```

```html
<ul id="list1">
  <li><a href="#">A</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">B</a></li>
</ul>

<a href="#" />
<input id="f" />
```

If I remove the keydown handler and the anchor element in between the textfield and the target anchor that I want to focus, the focus outline is rendered correctly.

Is this a known Chrome bug, and are there any workarounds for this? (Using Chrome 74)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prevent the other anchor from gaining focus using the `tabindex` attribute. Here is an example:

```html
<ul id="list1">
  <li><a href="#">A</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">B</a></li>
</ul>

<a href="#" tabindex="-1"/>
<input id="f" />
```

This may not work in all browsers.

Answer (score 1):

You may consider removing `e.preventDefault();`, then wait a few milliseconds before setting the focus:

```js
document.getElementById("f").addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
    if (e.key === "Tab" && e.shiftKey) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            document.querySelector("#list1 > li:last-child > a").focus();
        }, 10);
    }
});
```

```html
<ul id="list1">
    <li><a href="#">A</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">B</a></li>
</ul>

<a href="#" />
<input id="f" />
```

Comment: yeah, a decent idea, though I prefer the tabindex approach